# What parts of speech are "like" and "to" in the sentence "Bobby does not like to walk"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech, infinitives

I realized that I want to be able to look at any sentence and understand
what each word in that sentence is in terms of its part of speech, since
I never really cared in school to learn the parts of speech thoroughly
(big mistake).

I think for the sentence:

> Bobby does not like to walk.

that *Bobby* is a noun, *does* is a verb, *not* is an adverb, and
that *walk* is a verb as well.

Is *to* a preposition? If so, why?

And what is the function of *like* in the sentence?

Comment: "To" is not a preposition but a subordinator -- it introduces the infinitival clause "to walk", functioning as complement of "like". "Like" is a verb functioning as predicator of the clause "like to walk".

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the parts of speech for every word in a sentence is a much overrated skill. Once you learn them, what do you do with them? And what if they didn't teach the whole list in grade school? Because they don't, you know -- the teachers don't know any more than their students, and none of them understand the textbook.

So, to answer your question, *like* is a verb and *to* is either a preposition or a complementizer, depending on how specific you want to be. *To* is the marker for an infinitive complement, and markers for complement clauses are called "complementizers". I don't make these up; that's just technical jargon. It looks like the preposition *to*, but it takes an infinitive verb phrase instead of a noun phrase as its "object". Call it what you like.

*To walk* is the object of *like* (or *not like*, since it's negative) and the implication is that what Bobby does not like is Bobby walking. Perhaps he wouldn't mind if somebody else walked; the sentence doesn't say.

There is a lot of structure in this sentence but it's not a string of beads with labels.

Comment: I'd say that "like" is a catenatve verb, so the clause "to walk" is not its object but its catenative complement.

Comment: I don't think the term _catenative_ adds any meaning so I don't use it. Verbs often combine, in many ways; most transitive verbs have objects, for instance.

Comment: By treating it as a catenative construction, it becomes clear that the clause "to walk" is (contrary to what you say) not the object of "like", but its complement.

Comment: That's only if you want (for some reason) to distinguish a "complement" from an "object" by saying that one occurs after "catenative" verbs. If you don't care about that, you can dispense with "catenative" as well, since it's otherwise meaningless.

Comment: It's perfectly normal and useful to distinguish complement and object, since the latter has distinctive properties that distinguish it from other complements. In the OP's example, there can be no justification for treating the clause "to walk" as an object. It's a complement. In my experience, students find the term 'catenative' useful.

Comment: So an object is a type of complement, in your terminology? And what **are** these distinctive properties that distinguish them? There are syntactic tests for them, one presumes.